# tel pattern for proper and common non-proper formatted phone numbers

Tags: html

I've come across some `pattern` values for the `type="tel"` such as `\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}` however I need a pattern that matches the proper pattern and two common non-proper formats:

- (123) 456-7890 (Proper)
- 123-456-7890
- 1234567890

The following *seems* to work for all three formats:

```
<input pattern="?(\d{3}?)? \d{3}?-\d{4}" type="tel" />
```

Is this valid or are there strings that aren't valid that this would still pass? Is this optimized well or is there a faster way to run the regular expression? Bonus: what can be done to properly support international telephone number formats?

Answer (score 0):

At w3schools I had it passing for example (1234567890 and jhj, which is not what you’re after.

However, a solution can be examined [here](https://regex101.com/r/8qgKd7/2).
It’s looking at all your example strings at the same time because the global flag is set. Flag settings are to the right of the pattern.
On the LHS there’s a regex debugger which shows how it worked it all out.
The explanation on the RHS explains what all the symbols are all about.

The pattern should match only the formats specified.

pattern=”\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{10}”

It looks very complicated, but on inspection is your

proper pattern | 1st non-proper format | 2nd non-proper format

(123) 456-7890 | 123-456-7890 | 1234567890

”\(  \d{3}  \)  \s  \d{3}  -  \d{4}  |  \d{3}  -  \d{3}  -  \d{4}  |  \d{10}”